# Should the y-axis on a survival plot go from 0 to 100 even if the lines are all above 0.9?

Tags: survival, data-visualization

I am reviewing an article that includes a survival plot, with % survival on the y-axis and time on the x-axis. The y-axis goes from 0 to 100, but the two survival curves are both always above 90%.

I can see reasons for changing the y-axis to (say) 80 to 100: It will be easier to distinguish the lines and easier to see just how they are.

I can also see reasons for leaving it 0 to 100: It is clearer that the vast majority survive.

I have read some similar debates about other types of plots, but not about survival plots. Is there a "best practices" here? Am I missing any good reasons to prefer one or the other?

Comment: I don't think the fact that this is a survival plot changes the fundamental principles of data visualization that we discuss in other contexts.  Which is better depends on whether it is more important to show local changes over time / between the 2 curves, or if it is more important to show that the overwhelming majority survive either way.

Comment: Since this statistic has boundaries on two ends, not only zero but also hundred. You could plot *'100% - survival'*. The amount that does not survive. At least, if the context won't  require the use of an explicit survival plot (e.g. because elsewhere in the article survival plots are used as well or because it is compared with other research that uses survival plots). But, if comparison with other works are important then possibly plot everything on an axis that starts at 0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bar charts should start at 0*, because the lengths of the bars (distances from top to bottom of each bar) are what your eye compares.

But for line charts (whether survival or any other), there's no hard and fast rule. It depends on the primary goal of the chart:

- If the goal is to show that the vast majority survive, keep it at 0 to 100.
- If the chart is being shown so that readers can compare nuanced differences between the lines, zoom in to 80 to 100.

Also on the context:

- Since this is in a scientific article, presumably the reader has time to read the axis limits carefully and to think about the graph in context of the rest of the article. There's little chance of being misled by zooming in the y-axis to 80 to 100.
- If this graph were in a format where the graph is only shown briefly (slide show or video), readers can't be expected to read the axis labels quickly enough before the graph disappears. So unless the presenter points it out, readers might not realize that the y-axis is zoomed in. In that case, you might want to err on the side of keeping the full y-axis of 0 to 100.

Naomi Robbins' book *Creating More Effective Graphs* is a great resource for best practices. She collects and summarizes advice from many dataviz experts, illustrates each best practice with a few examples, and points out where the rules of thumb can go wrong.

---

*(or other reference point, as @AdamO notes in the comments. Usually the length of each bar represents a "difference from 0," so 0 must be included on the y-axis to show the whole bar. But if the length of each bar represents a difference from some other reference value, the y-axis range needn't include 0---it just needs to be wide enough to include all of each bar. If you want a narrower y-axis, just use dots or lines instead of bars.)

Comment: I question whether there is really a hard and fast rule that bar charts *have to* start at 0, but other than that this is exactly the right answer.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Usually I'd be happy to hedge my answer with a "usually"! But I genuinely cannot think of a situation where it would be useful & not misleading to use a bar chart that doesn't start at zero. Do you know of any such situations? (I guess if the bars are not aligned with a common baseline, it might be OK; but I would call that a "waterfall chart" or something, not a "bar chart.")

Comment: Is it "size of bars" or "height of bars"?

Comment: @civilstat here's an example: median household income vs the federal poverty line. We don't need the barchart to go down to zero, our eye is focused on the FPL which is in the middle and the Y-axis should span the range.

Comment: @dipetkov "Height of bars" feels slightly ambiguous to me when the y-axis is not clear: does "height" mean the y-value where the bar ends, or the distance from bottom to top of the bar? The latter is what I meant by "size."

Comment: @AdamO Good call! If the bars are showing "differences above & below a reference point" and that reference point is not 0, the y-axis should span the range. It does not need to include 0 -- but it does need to include the reference point. (If all the bars are positive or all negative, we still want to show the whole bars, not just the range of the differences-from-ref-point.) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Size of bars is more ambiguous to me than height, hence the comment. Either way, I'd say that when you need clarification of what you mean by word "word", then it's kind of ambigous.

Comment: @dipetkov Duly noted and edited. Hopefully clearer now.

Comment: @civilstat, for better or worse, the most common use of barcharts is to show a set of group means.  First, consider a case where $0$ isn't meaningful (eg, means of likert items with scores $[1, 7]$).  Alternatively, consider any case where the goal is to display the differences between the groups (ie, not absolute heights) and the differences are small relative to the numbers—the differences become invisible in order to show $0$ (eg, business revenue under different policies).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately I agree this is common practice, but I strongly believe it's misleading and hence a bad idea. If 0 isn't meaningful, we simply shouldn't use bars -- use dots instead, for example as here: https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/visualizing-amounts.html#dot-plots-and-heatmaps

Comment: @civilstat, I'm very familiar with dot plots.  Cleveland invented them based on his research that people are best at extracting horizontal distances & that can be presented in line with Tufte-style principles using dots.  I often use dot plots myself, but clients are not typically used to them & find them foreign instead of more intuitive.  I've made barcharts for people more than once.

Comment: Many people believe there are fixed rules for plots that you *have to* follow no matter what.  The author at your link implicitly does, eg: "One important limitation of bars is that they need to start at zero, so that the bar length is proportional to the amount shown".  Says who?  This didn't come down the mountain on a stone tablet.  Bars simply present (horizontal or vertical) distances, w/ their width usually a meaningless attribute.  Dots don't have the added, meaningless attribute, but also only display distances (usually horizontal, but can also be vertical).

Comment: Which is easier depends on how much the unnecessary width is a distraction vs viewers' comfort with them.  As I say, I have made bars for people & I'm ultimately fine with that.  The claim that bar "bar length [has to be] proportional to the amount shown" has no physiological or psychological basis.  It assumes there is something about bars that necessitates the proportional differences as the important piece of information, rather than the absolute difference.  But the difference between bars and dots is just that one has a width that the other doesn't.

Comment: The plot of life expectancies could have used bars w/o going to 0 & have displayed the same information as the dot plot.  In the end, some people believe there are fixed rules that you have to follow, but I don't.  I gather you & the linked author fall into the former category, and so we aren't going to agree here & will end up just talking past each other.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I don't think we are talking past each other, although I'd be happy to move this sidebar elsewhere b/c it's not directly related to the OP's question. (1) I agree with you that there aren't fixed rules & the guide should be: Which graph will your reader understand? If your clients find dot plots unintuitive, and you're *sure* that they are interpreting cut-off bars correctly, then use bars. (2) At the same time, as you note, "Cleveland invented them based on his research..." and such perceptual research is why many recommend starting bars at 0 (or whatever baseline).

Comment: Some "rules" are a matter of taste (like many of Tufte's!), but I'm pretty confident this one rests on empirical research on humans reading graphs. For the typical reader, a bar going from 40 to 60 looks like "twice as much" as a bar from 40 to 50. It takes conscious deliberate mental effort to suppress this instinct and read the 60 as only 20% larger than 50. With the dot plot, you still have to read the 60 and 50 carefully, but at least you're not fighting against an *instinct to misread it* at the same time. Still, if your clients do actually read cut-off bars correctly, great!

Comment: @civilstat, as far as I know, Cleveland doesn't say anywhere that either bars or dots have to be plotted on an axis that starts at 0.  I'll leave it at that.  +1 for this answer.  Good luck.

Comment: Again, I agree context matters more than fixed rules, but since you did mention Cleveland: "...a bar chart should not be used when there is no meaningful baseline, since the bar lengths would encode meaningless numbers." On page 832 of Cleveland & McGill (1985), "Graphical Perception and Graphical Methods for Analyzing Scientific Data" https://www.jstor.org/stable/1695272

Comment: I was bothered by the "median household income vs federal poverty line" example. (For one, there is the complexity of cost of living, which makes the lengths hard to compare let alone the origin.) So I wanted to check how the US government tends to report this info. Here is the census.gov page on [Income in the United States: 2021-Current Population Reports](https://tinyurl.com/yc4uym3z). TLDR: They let their charts extend to 0. The most interesting graph might be [Median income between 1959 and 2021](https://tinyurl.com/3nrctfxw) (in 2021 dollars). It has a broken y-axis which extends to 0.

Answer (score 15):

I have seen it both ways. It depends on the message you are trying to send. It's true that non-statisticians (and some statisticians) are likely to be confused and miss it if the Y-axis starts at anything other than 0. In a *huge* study, you can have curves that barely cross 95% survival with hazard ratios of astounding magnitude (0.5 or lower) and significant $p$-values. Another "confusion" in the community might be why an analysis is so well powered but the graph "doesn't show anything". Hopefully statisticians understand that 100,000s of people in an analysis without events are the explanation here, but they'd be right to question "if the graph really does anything" - we shouldn't say it did or didn't based on the *results*, that is an *a posteriori* finding.

Alternately, you could include a *cumulative incidence plot*, which can be defined as 1-S(t).

Example from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336983997_Morphomic_Signatures_Derived_from_Computed_Tomography_Predict_Hepatocellular_Carcinoma_Occurrence_in_Cirrhotic_Patients).
[image]

Comment: There is a great deal to be said for the incidence plot.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, starting the graph above zero is preferable, as it allows the viewer to more easily digest the information, which is the point of the graph.  You do have to be careful to not mislead the viewer into such misperceptions as that twice the distance from the bottom means twice the value. You can emphasize that it doesn't start at zero, such as by having [squiggly lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79269/how-to-show-the-data-does-not-start-at-zero-symbol-on-a-pgfplot-graph) . Depending on the context, you might want to just change the variable from "survival" to something like "attrition", and show 1-survival; going from 90% to 95% is a small percentage change in survival, but half the attrition (going from 10% to 5%), so the question arises as to which is more pertinent.

Comment: I am not familiar with the subject, but "complementary cdf" and "cdf" are two names from probability theory that could work better.